# Why is an operator== not sufficient for an std::unordered_map? - C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, unordered

Why do I need to implement both the == operator and a random operator returning a size_t? And what should the method returning size_t actually return?

EDIT: When I said random operator, I didn't mean it had no use. What I meant is, in my eyes, I do not see what use it has, hence the last question. 7

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: You don't need a random operator. You need to implement a hash function returning a `size` for a given keyed type instance. This is because `unordered_map` is a hash map.

Comment: What is it used for though? @juanchopanza

Comment: What is a _random operator_?

Comment: To hash the elements. Read the wikipedia link on hash tables. It basically creates a key for an object, and depending on that key, the object gets places somewhere in the table.

Comment: @juanchopanza so they are sorted? WikiPedia isn't really helping. There is too much irrelevant information that it's hard to see something useful.

Comment: @Binero Hashing 2 distinct, unequal elements may produce the same hash result (collision). In that case the elements will need to be compared for equality. It's all explained in the Wikipedia link.

Comment: @Praetorian So I could just always return the same hash because it'll be checked anyways? (AKA it's just for performance?)

Comment: You could always return the same hash, but then you would bet O(N) lookup always.

Comment: If you want *O(n)* operation out of your `unordered_map`, go ahead and do that!

Comment: And if you had read the wikipedia article all of this would make perfect sense :-)

Comment: off topic: @juanchopanza I had read some of it, I didn't read all. It explained how hashing worked in a book form. Right now I know too and it only took me 2 to 3 comments.

Comment: @Binero - how would you write an unordered_map using just == and get the complexity guarantees?

Comment: @Binero You need to read about hash maps. If you don't care about getting O(1) performance then you shouldn't be using a hash map anyway.

Comment: I would hope that the hash function is not *random*...

Comment: @bames53 Assumptions! I never said I didn't! I asked if it'd work if  I did that, not to actually use it, but to get a greater understanding of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hashed container (hashtable, hashmap, unordered map) uses a hash-function to generate a single integer value to represent an index (or key) for the entry. This makes for a very quick-lookup, since (assuming we have a good spread of hash values) once we have the hash, we just need to look at that index. Most other storage methods means comparing a bunch of things until the right element is found.

There is really only two rules about hash-keys:
 1. You get the same key for a given input each time the hash-function is called. 
 2. The value is different for different input - it doesn't HAVE to be unique, but the more spread you get from similar input, the better.